# Tinymce 6 - Plugin problem after migration from 5 to 6

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-6

I have a problem with a plugin that was written for version 5. I found the cause, but I don't know how to fix this problem. In version 5 * during initialization eg.

```
tinymce.init ({
  selector: '#textarea',
  language: 'pl',
  external_filemanager_path: "test / test"
})
```

I was able to download the data via "**editor.settings.external_filemanager_path**". It doesn't work at this point. I tried to use "**editor.options.get ('external_filemanager_path')**" but it throws me "**undefined**". I don't only have access to "my" data. I can download typical data for tinymce without any problems.

Sorry for my English (PL).

**EDIT.**

I have one more problem. Unable to get data while executing functions during initialization, e.g.

```
tinymce.init({
   ***
   external_filemanager_path: 'xyz',
   file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
      openmanager();
   }
});

function openmanager() {
   ***
   const test =  tinymce.options.get('external_filemanager_path');
}
```

`* .options` does not work

Answer (score 1):

In TinyMCE 6 the settings have to be registered before you can get them.

For example in your plugin you should have:

```js
editor.options.register('external_filemanager_path', {
  processor: 'string',
  default: ''
});
```

After that point you should be able to call `editor.options.get('external_filemanager_path')` to get the value of the setting.

The `processor` can be one of the possible options (`'string'`, `'number'`, `'boolean'`, `'array'`, `'function'`, `'object'`, `'string[]'`, `'object[]'`, `'regexp'`) which allows that type, or it can be a function that takes in the value and return a boolean indicating if it is valid, or it can be a function that takes in the value and returns an object with a `valid` boolean property and a `value` property if it is valid or an `message` string property if it is invalid.

The typescript types for this are visible at the top of this file:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/api/EditorOptions.ts#L6-L52

At the moment the docs are a bit lacking however this will eventually be fully documented on the page:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editoroptions/

Comment: OMG, thank you very much. Yes, I thought you have to register first, but in the tests I didn't add these 2 values. Now everything is clear: D Thanks again.

Comment: I have one more problem. Unable to get data while executing functions during initialization
`* .options`  does not work

Comment: @tarzinio at runtime options are per editor, so try `tinymce.activeEditor.options.get()`

Comment: thank you. In his free time he will try: D